# Low doubling-dimension high connectivity graph

Tags: graph-theory

The doubling dimension of a metric space $(X, d)$ is defined as the smallest constant $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x\in X$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ the ball of radius $r$ around $x$ can be $2^r$ balls of radius $\frac{r}{2}$.

Analogously, the doubling dimension of a graph $G=(V, E)$ is defined as the doubling dimension of the shortest path metric associated with the $G$.

I am interested in finding a(n infinite) class of graph that has low doubling dimensions yet high connectivity. Ideally, the graphs are also sparse. Can someone point me to a class of graphs that has this property?

I was looking into expander graphs as they are sparse and have high connectivity, but I could not determine their doubling dimension. Can someone tell me how to determine the doubling dimension of an (expander) graph?